# Python Generated String in C

Tags: python, c, arrays, char, strcat

I need to generate the following string in C:

```
$(python -c "print('\x90' * a + 'blablabla' + '\x90' * b + 'h\xef\xff\xbf')")
```

where a and b are arbitrary integers and blablabla represents an arbitrary string. I am attempting to do this by first creating

```
char str1[size];
```

and then doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i+=1) {

strcat(str1, "\x90");

}
```

Next I use strcat again:

```
strcat(str1, "blablabla");
```

and I run the loop again, this time `b` times, to concatenate the next `b` `x90` characters. Finally, I use strcat once more as follows:

```
strcat(str1, "h\xef\xff\xbf");
```

However, these two strings do not match. Is there a more efficient way of replicating the behaviour of python's `*` in C? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Using `strcat` in a loop like that is quadratic, as described in one of my favorite blog posts (by one of the founders of Stack Overflow): http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html In addition to being a good read, it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char str1[size];
```

Even assuming you calculated size correctly, I recommend using

```
char * str = malloc(size);
```

Either way, after you get the needed memory for the string one way or the other, you gonna have to initialize it by first doing

```
str[0]=0;
```

if you intend in using `strcat`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i+=1) {
    strcat(str1, "\x90");
}
```

This is useful, if `"\x90"` actually is a string (i.e. something composed of more than one character) **and** that string is **short** (hard to give a hard border, but something about 16 bytes would be tops) **and** `a` is rather small[1]. Here, as [John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman) already suggested, `memset` is a better way to do it.

```
memset(str, '\x90', a);
```

Because you know the location, where `"blablabla"` shall be stored, just store it there using `strcpy` instead of `strcat`

```
// strcat(str1, "blablabla");
strcpy(str + a, "blablabla");
```

However, you need the address of the character after `"blablabla"` (one way or the other). So I would not even do it that way but instead like this:

```
const char * add_str = "blablabla";
size_t sl = strlen(add_str);
memcpy(str + a, add_str, sl);
```

Then, instead of your second loop, use another `memset`:

```
memset(str + a + sl, '\x90', b);
```

Last but not least, instead of `strcat` again `strcpy` is better (here, `memcpy` doesn't help):

```
strcpy(str + a + sl + b, "h\xef\xff\xbf");
```

But you need it's size for the size calculation at the beginning, so better do it like the blablabla string anyway (and remember the tailing `'\0'`).

Finally, I would put all this code into a function like this:

```
char * gen_string(int a, int b) {
    const char * add_str_1 = "blablabla";
    size_t sl_1 = strlen(add_str_1);
    const char * add_str_2 = "h\xef\xff\xbf";
    size_t sl_2 = strlen(add_str_2);

    size_t size = a + sl_1 + b + sl_2 + 1;
    // The + 1 is important for the '\0' at the end

    char * str = malloc(size);
    if (!str) {
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(str, '\x90', a);
    memcpy(str + a, add_str_1, sl_1);
    memset(str + a + sl_1, '\x90', b);
    memcpy(str + a + sl_1 + b, add_str_2, sl_2);
    str[a + sl_1 + b + sl_2] = 0; // 0 is the same as '\0'

    return str;
}
```

Remember to `free()` the retval of `gen_string` at some point.

If the list of `memset` and `memcpy` calls get longer, then I'd suggest to do it like this:

```
    char * ptr = str;
    memset(ptr, '\x90',    a   ); ptr += a;
    memcpy(ptr, add_str_1, sl_1); ptr += sl_1;
    memset(ptr, '\x90',    b   ); ptr += b;
    memcpy(ptr, add_str_2, sl_2); ptr += sl_2;
    *ptr = 0; // 0 is the same as '\0'
```

maybe even creating a macro for `memset` and `memcpy`:

```
#define MEMSET(c, l) do { memset(ptr, c, l); ptr += l; } while (0)
#define MEMCPY(s, l) do { memcpy(ptr, s, l); ptr += l; } while (0)

    char * ptr = str;
    MEMSET('\x90',    a   );
    MEMCPY(add_str_1, sl_1);
    MEMSET('\x90',    b   );
    MEMCPY(add_str_2, sl_2);
    *ptr = 0; // 0 is the same as '\0'

#undef MEMSET
#undef MEMCPY
```

For the justifications why to do it the way I recommend it, I suggest you read the blog post [Back to Basics](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) (by one of the founders of Stack Overflow) which happens not only to be John Coleman's favorite blog post but mine also. There you will learn, that using `strcat` in a loop like the way you tried it first has quadratic run time and hence, why not use it the way you did it.

[1] If `a` is big and/or the string that needs to be repeated is long, a better solution would be something like this:

```
const char * str_a = "\x90";
size_t sl_a = strlen(str_a);

char * ptr = str;
for (size_t i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
    strcpy(ptr, str_a);
    ptr += sl_a;
}
// then go on at address str + a * sl_a
```

Answer (score 0):

For individual 1-byte chars you can use `memset` to partially replicate the behavior of Python's `*`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    char buffer[100];

    memset(buffer,'#',10);
    buffer[10] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    memset(buffer, '*', 5);
    buffer[5] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
##########
*****
```

For a more robust solution, see [this](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#C).